# How to Update multiple rows in SQL using a CURSOR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, sql-update

Below is my SQL update that i was trying and didnt work. But it worked for a single record integer update while using @sampids as INT data type. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
DECLARE @sampids AS NVARCHAR(1000)='10,20,30'   
DECLARE @sampcursorno AS INT=0

DECLARE sample_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT VALUE FROM Split(@sampids,',')
OPEN sample_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM sample_cursor INTO @sampcursorno

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   

        UPDATE tbl_Testing
        SET SampId = @sampcursorno

        FETCH NEXT FROM sample_cursor INTO @sampcursorno

    END

CLOSE sample_cursor

DEALLOCATE sample_cursor
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@sampids,',')

Comment: Your update doesn't have a `where` clause. So each iteration of the cursor ALL rows are updated. When the cursor is finished all rows will be updated with whatever value came last (you also have no control over that, btw.).

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I am expecting to get an output as below

ColA      ColB     SampId
 Brad       A1          10  
 Richie     B1          20
 Mark       C1          30
 George   D1          NULL

But the whole column Samp Id is filled only with 30

Comment: My comment explains that. What is the logic behind your expected results? Why does Brad get SampId 10?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include that expected output, it's very hard to read in a comment

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to update the original table, replacing each `sampId` with each respective index in the input csv list.

There is no `split()` function in SQL Server. You can't use `string_split()`, because it does not guarantee the order in which parts are returned.

One option is to split the input string with a recursive query, and then use the resulting dataset for update:

```
declare @sampids as nvarchar(1000)='10,20,30';

with cte as (
    select 
        1 id,
        cast(substring(@sampids, 1, charindex(',', @sampids) - 1) as int) sampid,
        substring(@sampids + ',', charindex(',', @sampids) + 1, len(@sampids)) rest
    union all
    select 
        id + 1,
        cast(substring(rest, 1, charindex(',', rest) - 1) as int),
        substring(rest, charindex(',', rest) + 1, len(rest))
    from cte
    where charindex(',', rest) > 0
)
update t
set sampid = c.id
from tbl_Testing t
inner join cte c on c.sampid = t.sampid
```